# SQL Server XML data type combine multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2014

I have a SQL Server 2014 table containing hundreds of XML rows. All the xml objects have the same structure.

```
create table table1
(
    createdOn datetime,
    row xml
)
```

How can I query multiple rows (about 20 files show up daily and they must be stored as received)?

Row 1

```
<Products>
  <product>
    <productID>1</productID>
    <product>Bilberry</product>
    <price>10</price>
  </product>
  <product>
    <productID>2</productID>
    <product>Lychee</product>
    <price>5</price>
  </product>
</Products>
```

Row 2

```
<Products>
  <product>
    <productID>3</productID>
    <product>Mango</product>
  </product>
  <product>
    <productID>4</productID>
    <product>Blackcurrant</product>
  </product>
</Products>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for deleting the answer provided

It worked perfectly

```
SELECT 
    ID
    ,Tab.Col.value('productID[1]', 'int') as ProductID
FROM   [dbo].table1 a
       CROSS APPLY a.XMLData.nodes('/Products/product') Tab(Col)
```

Thanks